# Get the Latest date from the Three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
ID     Date1           Date2            Date3   
158    5/3/13 15:11    2/20/13 11:38    2/20/13 11:38
```

I want to get the latest date from this three columns.

Comment: Use the case statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Date1 IS NOT NULL 
             AND Date1>=COALESCE(Date2,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2)) 
             AND Date1>=COALESCE(Date3,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2)) THEN Date1 
            WHEN Date2 IS NOT NULL 
             AND Date2>=COALESCE(Date1,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2))
             AND Date2>=COALESCE(Date3,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2)) THEN Date2 
            WHEN Date3 IS NOT NULL 
             AND Date3>=COALESCE(Date1,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2))
             AND Date3>=COALESCE(Date2,CAST('0001-01-01 00:00' AS DATETIME2)) THEN Date3 
       END AS latest
FROM t1
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/475f7/1)

Comment: suppose in one there is no data null is there. i have to take latest of other two columns.

Comment: @Notulysses what if all three dates are same.

Comment: @Aniket : then the first WHEN will succeed and return Date1 (=Date2=Date3)

Comment: It is not working.. it is showing null value only as latest.

Comment: No I am getting this error "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2". I am checking...

Comment: Please help me to get the proper result I am getting this error - "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with datetime2"

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CASE`:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN Date1>=Date2 AND  Date1>=Date3 THEN Date1
            WHEN Date2>=Date1 AND  Date2>=Date3 THEN Date2
            WHEN Date3>=Date1 AND  Date3>=Date2 THEN Date3
      END AS GreatestDate
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Are you sure that works, when is Date1 returned?

Comment: @CSL: Oops! Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date1 > date2 AND date1 > date3 THEN date1
            WHEN date2 > date3 THEN date2
            ELSE date3 END MaxDate
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using UNPIVOT

```
SELECT MAX(MaxDt) MaxDt
   FROM tbl 
UNPIVOT
   (MaxDt FOR E IN 
      (Date1, Date2, Date3)
)AS unpvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
 select case when Date1 > Date 2 then case when Date1 > Date3 then Date1 end
        when Date2 > Date3 then Date2   
       else  Date3 from <yortable>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Date1 >= Date2 AND Date1 >= Date3 THEN Date1
    WHEN Date2 >= Date1 AND Date2 >= Date3 THEN Date2
    WHEN Date3 >= Date1 AND Date3 >= Date2 THEN Date3
    ELSE Date1
END AS MostRecentDate
```

OR

```
SELECT  MAX(date_columns) AS max_date
       FROM    
       ( 
          (SELECT date1 AS date_columns FROM tablename)
          UNION
          (SELECT date2 AS date_columns FROM tablename)
          UNION
          (SELECT date3 AS date_columns FROM tablename)
       ) AS date_query
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...:)

```
select top 1 a.date from
(
select Date1 as date from table_name where Id='158'
union
select Date2 as date from table_name where Id='158'
union
select Date3 as date from table_name where Id='158'
)a
order by a.date DESC;
```